# AMP - Install multiple event handlers for tap

Tags: amp-html

Is there a way to install multiple events for tap? E.g. on tap close the sidebar and open a lightbox?

Thanks.

Comment: https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/amp-actions-and-events/

Answer (score 10):

**Handling multiple events**
You can listen to multiple events on an element by separating the events with a semicolon ;.

Example: `on="submit-success:lightbox1;submit-error:lightbox2"`

**Multiple actions for one event**
You can execute multiple actions in sequence for the same event by separating the actions with a comma ','.

Example: `on="tap:target1.actionA,target2.actionB"`

Comment: Multiple actions for the same event doesn't work for me. :( (amp-bind-0.1)

Answer (score 5):

There doesn't appear to be a way to chain actions.

You could try;

```
<button on="tap:my-lb.open" on="tap:sidebar1.close">test</button>
```

Or

```
<button on="tap:my-lb.open,sidebar1.close">test</button>
```

Comment: Neither of them has worked for me.... Is there actually some other solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The use of semicolons makes this possible.

```
<button on="tap:my-lb.open;tap:sidebar1.close">test</button>
```

https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/spec#on

*P.S.: I'm not sure if it works on the same event twice. But it works with different ones like `tap:action;change:action`*

Comment: Oh boy, sorry this is a duplicate from the best answer – which I did not see when I was looking this up. [Right Answer from Toby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/197302/toby)

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work using one `on` attribute just fine:

```
<button on="tap:lightbox-1.close,lightbox-2">Next</button>
```

Comment: concatenation of events for the same element works well, but the question is if diffrent elements may be target with an tap event.

Comment: @ChristianFelix It's been a while since I worked in Amp or looked at the code where I did this, but I think this *was* for two different elements (`lightbox-1` and `lightbox-2`).

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to multiple events on an element by separating the events with a semicolon ;.

Example: `on="submit-success:lightbox1;submit-error:lightbox2"`

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
on="tap:my-lightbox,sidebar.close"
```

Answer (score 0):

To trigger multiple componets with tap on a single component, you need to separate componentX.action parts with commas. Here **ans16** and **explanation16** are two components to be **shown or hidden** after tapping.

```
<div on="tap:ans16.toggleVisibility,explanation16.toggleVisibility" role="button" tabindex="16">Answer[=]</div>
<div id="ans16" hidden>D</div>
<div id="explanation16" hidden>Explanation: </div>
```

Check [here](https://www.examtray.com/java-questions/java-classes-objects-interview-mcq-questions-answers-1?amp) for a working amp page. It also uses role and tabindex attributes which are required to **qualify for** a Google AMP page indexing.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the tabindex requirement for a 'Google AMP page indexing'? I can't find any info on it, thanks.

Comment: Google search console reports errors for missing these tags. I do not have exact documentation.